# add script to Jquery template

Tags: jquery, templates

Can I execute jQuery script syntax like,

```
$('some-selector').val(${data});
```

inside my jQuery template?

How do I hook up event handlers for controls inside the jQuery template, where the event handler is in the template, without writing script outside the template?

So, I know this doesn't work:

```
<script id="modal-edit-mail" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<button id="killswitch">Stop Now</button>
$('#killswitch').click(function(){some function});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**To your first question:**

Yes, you can place Javascript expressions (including function calls) inside your templates using the `${expr}` or `{{= expr}}` syntax. These examples all worked for me using Chrome:

```
${myTemplateVariable}
${Math.max(Math.min(1, myTemplateVariable), 4)}
${$("#test").html()}
{{= String({"foo": "bla"})}}
```

But there are some problems:

- Curly braces are often a problem for jQuery. That's why in the last example I had to use the alternative `{{= }}` syntax.
- Some JavaScript expressions are not allowed due to security concerns, e.g. Google Chrome won't let you use **eval** in your templates.

Additionally, if the code you want to include in your template is rather complex it is a good idea to define a function on the special $item template variable. E.g.

```
$("#myTemplate").tmpl(myData, {"myComplexFunction": function () {
    // doing complex stuff here
    (...)
    return someBadAssValue;
}}).appendTo("#myTargetElement");
```

Then you could write the following template code:

```
${$item.myComplexFunction()}
```

See the documentation of the second parameter to the tmpl function: http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/

---

**To your second question (how to hook up event handlers):**

When I used jQuery I wrote separate functions for updating each part of a page with the current data. To that end, the functions would empty() certain `div`s in the page and render the new content with the appropriate jQuery templates. In the very same functions I then re-configured all event handlers, i.e. after the new HTML has been inserted into the page.

I know that there is some (badly/not documented) update() method with which jQuery templates can be updated more directly, but I think that would still require you to reconfigure your event handlers (in case new interactive elements had been added by the update).

EDIT:
To know which element triggered a certain event, I used HTML-IDs that included the data element's ID, e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:void" id="remove_person_5">Remove</a>
```

And this JS code for setting up the event handlers:

```
$("[id^='remove_person_']").click(handle_remove_person);
```

Answer (score 0):

No - it's a template. Templates are meant to separate presentation and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate JS script that adds the functionality you want. In the `<head>` section of your page, just add a link to it thusly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="killswitch.js"></script>
```

Then, in killswitch.js, add the selector and click function, like you have above, inside a `ready` function so that it fires when the whole page finishes loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#killswitch').click(function(){some function});
});
```

Comment: maybe I should change my example to clarify the need: I have a modal template that I'm using for edits to an address block.  the address block gets read out of my .data so I need a way to set the value of the state select list. normally, I'd have a function with a variable that finds the read only version of the state: var state =('.state').text(); and then the function would set the correct value in the select list: $('#state-field').val(state). so how do I do that in a template?

Comment: I don't think that clarified anything. Why can't you use this method?